# Can I change single shutoff valve to double shutoff valve on hot and cold water lines for twin sinks?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, vanity

Can I change single to double vanity and use double shirt valves on supply lines?

Also, the sinks will be 30 inches apart. So I can drain the second sink as shown?

[image]

Comment: The fitting in the picture is a sanitary tee, not a wye.

Comment: Yes I know. Should I be using a wye?

Comment: No, just an observation that the picture you're posting has an incorrect description of what it is.  I'd do it using normal double sink fittings before the slip fit entry to drain pipe, as double kitchen sinks are normally done, rather than making the cross-connect with drain pipes and kludging it with a Fernco coupling like that.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one post. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Is this about supply lines or drain pipes?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a double shutoff valve on the hot and cold lines. They make "TEE" fittings that go into a single shutoff and branch off to two sinks. Just make sure you can get braided supply lines long enough to get to both sinks.

Your draining configuration will work too but will take up a lot of room under your vanity. The tail pipes for bathroom sinks are longer than for kitchen sinks so double check your clearances from them to the drain trap.

Comment: So I don’t need to have a separate shutoff for each faucett and can just use a Tee off of single shutoff valve

Comment: Tailpeices can (and usually should) be trimmed to fit. Just don't overdo it (they have a range of adjustment in the slip fittings.)

Comment: @Lance You can use a Tee but they might be hard to find.  It would just screw on to your shutoff valve like a braided supply line.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  The tail pieces also have the stopper that takes up space that the kitchen tail pieces don't have.  That's what I was actually referring to.

Comment: You guys are great. Short of opening the wall and reconfiguring the drain pipes what can I do to take up less room in the vanity?  Thanks

Comment: @Lance some styles of sinks have shorter stoppers so you can cut the tailpiece down further. Or you could go with no built in stopper and use a separate plug instead.

Comment: Just cut the tailpiece on the furthest sink to the minimum length that will still let you operate the stopper.  You don't indicate if you need a popup stopper or one of those lever style stoppers.